# How to update app activities when an sms is received?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast

I'm creating an sms app and at the moment when I receive an sms I'm able to create a notification that, when clicked, launches the app.

But what if the sms is received while the user is in the app? how can I make the activity update itself?

I'm using a BroadcastReceiver and I launch a PendingIntent when the notification is clicked.

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            0,
            resultIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put another receiver in the activity like so

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SMS_RECEIVED");

    private BroadcastReceiver refreshReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
            refresh();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        context.unregisterReceiver(refreshReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        context.registerReceiver(refreshReceiver, filter);
        refresh();
    }

}
```

Comment: I have a custom broadcastreceiver do I have to set the type of intent ("my.app.name.INTENT") somewhere?

Comment: The intent you have in the manifest (for example android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL), put that string in the IntentFilter in the activity. Don't register the new receiver in your manifest as it might cause errors. Leave your other BroadcastReceiver (the one that notifies the user) as it is. for now.

Comment: I have another problem now, I read the sms from content://sms but it seems that it's stored there after the notifcation has been delivered, in fact the sms app notifcation is being delivered after my app notification. should I delay it?

Comment: I'm not sure sorry, never worked with SMS that much.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @dlee is correct, but the IntentFilter that is thrown when an SMS is received is this:

```
private IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
```